# Use aggregate functions in create function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I use below code to create function but when i want to execute it occur error

```
CREATE FUNCTION getFactorPriceFunction
(
    @factorCode BIGINT
)
RETURNS bigint
AS BEGIN
    RETURN 
    (
        select SUM(price*coun) as total from CustomerFactor inner join CustomerFactorDetails 
        on CustomerFactor.code=CustomerFactorDetails.factorCode inner join ProductDetails on
        ProductDetails.code=CustomerFactorDetails.productDetailsCode
        where factorCode=@factorCode AND final=1
    )
END
```

execute:

```
 select total from getFactorPriceFunction(100)
```

error:

> Invalid object name 'getFactorPriceFunction'

Comment: You have to qualify it with schema name: select total from dbo.getFactorPriceFunction(100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's called `dbo.getFactorPriceFunction`.
2. The invocation is goes like this:

   ```
   select dbo.getFactorPriceFunction(100) as total
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Since it is a `scalar value` function ,it should be executed like

```
select dbo.getFactorPriceFunction(100)
```

If you are returning a table then it should be

```
select total from dbo.getFactorPriceFunction(100)
```

Comment: when i use your answer says: `'getFactorPriceFunction' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: It is because you are not using `dbo.getFactorPriceFunction(100)`. You need to understand the difference between `scalar` and `Table value` functions and how are they executed . Kindly read this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177499(v=sql.105).aspx) article